in visual c#, how can I write in messagebox right to left?
in visual c#, how can I write in messagebox right to left?
I have wrote a Persian message in messagebox in visual c#. but in showing, it has been aligned from left to right. I want to align this right to left. how can I do that?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%23%5D+right+to+left+textbox ?

You can use the options RightAlign and RtlReading on the MessageBoxOptions.
Here is a sample you can use :
MessageBox.Show(
    "Your message here", 
    "Your caption here", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Information, 
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
    MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign | MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading
);

You can review the details of the messagebox in this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-messagebox-show(system-string-system-string-system-windows-messageboxbutton-system-windows-messageboximage-system-windows-messageboxresult-system-windows-messageboxoptions)
and the avaible options :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messageboxoptions?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
 
